# Get the most popular value into array type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such a table:

```
               Table "public.items_tags_array"
 Column  |       Type        |           Modifiers           
---------+-------------------+-------------------------------
 item_id | character varying | not null
 tags    | text[]            | not null default '{}'::text[]
Foreign-key constraints:
    "items_tags_array_item_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id)
```

The tags field contains multiple elements in the array format:

```
   item_id    |       tags       
--------------+------------------
 8eb6a7d9558c | {test,home,sun}
 3779a64d1bf9 | {test2,home,fam}
```

How do I build a query to get the most popular tags (single values)?

Comment: To start with, if you have any control over the database structure, the tags should be stored one by one in a different table, and then you use a link table to join the tags to items. Comma-separated values in database fields is not a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unnest()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
select tag, count(tag)
from items_tags_array
cross join unnest(tags) as tag
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `unnest(anyarray)` (see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)) to get set of elements from the array. Then group by the tag and get the most popular.

```
SELECT
    tag,
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        unnest(tags) AS tag
    FROM
        items_tags_array
    ) AS tag
GROUP BY
    tag
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC;
```